# Prove that it is impossible to have 5 different positive integers, such that the sum of any two of them ends in a different digit?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example 1,2,3,5,9 isn't valid because 9+5=14(last digit 4) and 1+3=4 so they have the same last digit

Comment: For a start, work in arithmetic modulo 10.  Then you have only 10 values per number to consider.  In a mere $10^5$ cases, you could try all possibilities.

Comment: @badjohn Actually, since we can't have duplicates, and we don't care about the order, there are only $252$ cases to try.

Comment: You have $e$ even numbers, and $5-e$ odd numbers. How many sums will be even?

Comment: @DanielFischer Was just about to change my (deleted) answer into that. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Arthur Go ahead and change.

Comment: @Arthur I considered such a comment but I was happy just to reduce the apparently infinite number of cases to a finite number.  At least, I reduced to less than Graham's number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the contrary, that is, that there are $5$ positive integers $a,b,c,d,e$ such that every two of them sum numbers with different final digits. This is all the digits, because there are $10$ of these sums.

Since $0+1+\cdots+9=45$, the sum $S$ of the ten sums ends with $5$, but this is impossible because $$S=4(a+b+c+d+e)$$

Answer (score 1):

I was writing some overly complicated things about there being five even and five odd digits, but the essence of it was captured in a single sentence by Daniel Fischer in a comment above: You have $e$ even numbers and $e-5$ odd numbers. How many sums will be even?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to show that the case where all the numbers are minimised is not possible:

A simple group that has no sums ending in the same last digit is ${1, 2}$.

Let's extend this to $3$ numbers. Since $1 + 2 = 3$, the next digit that fulfils the requirements is $4$. Therefore, ${1, 2, 4}$ is also a valid group.

With $4$ numbers, we observe that $1 + 4 = 5$, and $2 + 4 = 6$. The next number we can fit in is $7$, and ${1, 2, 4, 7}$ is again, a valid group.

We can go back to the original problem with $5$ numbers now - since $1 + 7 = 8$, using our method the group ${1, 2, 4, 7, 9}$ is the only possible group with $5$ numbers. However, notice that $4 + 7$ and $2 + 9$ end in the same digit - $1$, so such a group of numbers is impossible.

Can you do the same for different groups of starting numbers, such as ${1, 3}$ or ${1, 4}$?